# Hook-content polynomial 2

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, young-tableaux

Recently I have proven the following identity 
\begin{align}
\sum_{\lambda\in \text{different hook of size d}} \frac{1}{d!} (-1)^{ht(\lambda)-1}  \, \dim \lambda \, \prod_{\Box \in \lambda} \frac{1}{1-c(\Box)h}&= \frac{(2d-2)!}{ (d-1)!}h^{d-1}\prod_{i=1}^{d-1} \frac{1}{(1+ih)(1-ih)}
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ denote the hook of size $d$,$c(\Box)$ denote the content of the hook. 
In the right-hand side of the equation if I replace $ \prod_{\Box \in \lambda} \frac{1}{1-c(\Box)h}$ by $ \prod_{\Box \in \lambda} (1-c(\Box)h)^2$ that is the following identity 
$$\sum_{\lambda\in \text{different hook of size d}} \frac{1}{|\lambda|!} (-1)^{ht(\lambda)-1}  \, \dim \lambda \, \prod_{\Box \in \lambda}(1-c(\Box)h)^2 $$
I could not predict a close form like the one I did for my first equation. 
Is there exist one? 
More interesting it looks close to the following formula which I have seen in a problem book of Enumerative Combinatorics vol 2 that is 
$$\sum_{w\in S_d}q^{k(w^2)}=\sum_{\Gamma}dim{\Gamma}\prod_{\Box\in \Gamma}(q+c(\Box))$$
where $\Gamma \vdash d$ is all the partititon of $d$ not only hook,$k(w^2)$ denote the number of cycles of $w^2\in S_n$.
So my identity has some combinatorial explanation like above?

Comment: Is it really $ |\lambda| ! $ in your first expression ? In which case, you could just replace it by $ d! $ since the hooks are all of size $d$.

Comment: have seen the related question, this seems to be the case. As remarked in your previous question, you have a particular polynomials in h. If you want a closed expression, first translate your sum into a sum on integers (the height of your hook) as done by D. Grinberg and then feed Maple/Mathematica with it. You will have immediately the answer. In case, if what comes out is too complicated, you can go to OEIS.

Comment: You are right it should be $d!$, I wrote in crude version.

Comment: We tried that out there is some symmetry notice but we could not get any nice form like previous ones.

Comment: Now, I am less convinced that there is a nice form. This is a convolution in the symmetric group, and the coefficients count some geodesic on it. I would try to see what are these coefficients. On the other hand, you found a nice form for the previous sum, and it involved homogeneous functions in Jucys-Murphy elements (see https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/512865/filename/induction_relations.pdf, this is related with unitary Weingarten elements). I am  curious : where does your problem come from ?

Comment: I have no idea about "convolution in symmetric group and coefficients counts geodesic" so I would take a look at the article you referred. It came out of a calculation about Hurwitz number it's very hard to tell you here.

Comment: Convolution in a group $G$ is defined by $ f * g(\sigma) = \sum_{\tau\in G} f(\sigma \tau^{-1}) g(\tau) = \sum_{a b = \sigma} f(a) g(b) $ for functions $ f, g : G \to \mathbb{C} $, say ; it is a very general concept (see wikipedia). By geodesic, I just meant the set $ \{ \sigma : C(\sigma) + C(\sigma c_d^{-1}) = k \} $. You can have a look at the introduction of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303312v2 (but this is just a question of vocabulary). At some point (when done), answer to this post with the reference of your article, I am interested to see the motivation.